# Prevent IntelliJ from marking errors for specific file extensions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, readme

IntelliJ has been indicating errors in a README.md file, how can I disable error checking for specific files or even specific file formats?

[image: Never gonna give you up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in IntelliJ IDEA:

[IDEA-220938](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-220938) False positive `class` or `interface` for Java in Markdown

For the time being, you can disable error checking in code fences:
[image]

Comment: How did you get that window?

Comment: Alt+Enter while the cursor at the highlighted word